# string in C: giving some logical error

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
char output[17]={0};
const char* change_mac(char ch[100])
{
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;

    bool flag = false;
    while(i < strlen(ch)) 
    {
        flag = false;
        int j = 0;
        while (j < 2)
        {
            if(ch[i] == ':' || strlen(ch) == i ) 
            {
                if(k != 0) 
                {
                    char temp = output[k-1];
                    output[k-1] = '0';
                    output[k] = temp;
                }
                flag = true;
            } 
            else 
            { 
                output[k] = ch[i];
            }
            i++;
            j++;
            k++;
        }
        if(i < strlen(ch) && memchr(ch, ':', strlen(ch)))
        {
            output[k] = ':';
            output[k+1] = '\0';
        }
        else{
            output[k] = ch[i];
        }
        k++;
        if(!flag) 
        {
            i++;
        }
    }

    output[k-1] = 0;
   return output;
}



int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
char name[]="";
char ch[100] = "0:0:0:0:0:0";

if(sscanf(argv[1],"%s",ch) == 1)
{
  name=change_mac(ch);
} 
return 0;
}
```

/*I suppose to get MAC as CMD line argue change it into proper format and store it in to this "name " variable So I can use it further   here It shows some typecast error*/

/* execute :    ./a.out 0:c:f4:dr:4r:1 */

Comment: you have to check `:` in `ch[]` at in if , `if(i !=sizeof(ch)){ output[k] = ':'; }` for 2nd

Comment: there's no try/catch construct in C, but there is in C++. I wouldn't advise to use it, other than for critical failure, because it is really expensive.

Comment: AndreasGrapentin saying true.. if you want to implement try-catch some time, this link will be useful [How do I implement exceptions with nestable try-catch-finally statement with messages in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779189/how-do-i-implement-exceptions-with-nestable-try-catch-finally-statement-with-mes) and http://www.nicemice.net/cexcept/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have changed you question in wrong way :(

I have corrected your code as below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    //char ch[] = {'0',':','1','0',':','1',':','C',':','B','F',':','9','8'};
    char ch[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','f'};
    char output[20]={0};
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;
    bool flag = false;

    while(i < sizeof(ch)) 
    {
        flag = false;
        int j = 0;
        while (j < 2)
        {
            if(ch[i] == ':') 
            {
                if(k != 0) 
                {
                    char temp = output[k-1];
                    output[k-1] = '0';
                    output[k] = temp;
                }
                flag = true;
            } 
            else 
            { 
                output[k] = ch[i];
            }
            i++;
            j++;
            k++;
        }
        if(i !=sizeof(ch) && memchr(ch, ':', sizeof(ch)))
        {
            output[k] = ':';
            output[k+1] = '\0';
        }
        else{ // added this else in your code
            output[k] = ch[i];
        }
        k++;
        if(!flag) 
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
    output[k-1] = 0;  // added this
    printf("%s\n",output);
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(ch));
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(output));

   return 0;
}
```

Its working good!

**case-1**  if `char ch[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g'};`

```
~$ ./a.out 
abcdefg
8
20
```

**case-2**  if `char ch[] = {'0',':','9',':','1',':','C',':','B',':','9','8'};`

```
:~$ ./a.out 
00:10:01:0C:BF:98
14
20
```

<sub>although it not good to give code, but because you are trying since morning I have given</sub>

Comment: char ch[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','f'}; and the output is  abcdefg !!!! not proper (last char is missing))   actualy its great .. the above code of mine is also working... Now I am working on a method for that I suppose to pass it ona command line arguement in main() and than call the function and return well formatted value .

Comment: @user95711 Yes you are correct...please review again this answer I made some more changes..This will work I hope..

Comment: I want to pass  "ch" as a command line argue. and put this logic on a separate function so  when I call It from a main function It shold make proper changes and return me that char array. Can you help me with that ?

Comment: @user95711 Yes you can do it..but you **have to change bit more** because this code is written for char array. further code need to be write in string.

Comment: @user95711 Try yourself ..otherwise I have changed your code that works on cmdline as you desired

Comment: yes I am trying...  It returns proper value if I take a global variable. but while I pass the string as parameter of function call it displeys " 00:)) " !!

Comment: @user95711 Read strings some **HINTS:** change `sizeof(ch)` with `strlen(ch)` ... pass `argv[1]` as `ch[]` ... Good Luck!

Comment: done.. but found another issue with your final code that it does not pad if the  last value has one char. !!!  e.g  0:6:44:f4:67:7  will give output 00:06:44:f4:67:7  !!! not 00:06:44:f4:67:70 !!!

Comment: @user95711 yes and this time you are to do like `output[k] = '\0';` instead `output[k-1] = '\0';`

Comment: this will create another proble... found the soln  (i < sizeof(ch)  and if((ch[i] == ':') || strlen(ch) == i)

Comment: @user95711 not understood :( but I guess you need something like `if(i !=strlen(ch) && memchr(ch, ':', strlen(ch)))`

Comment: I have changed (i != sizeof(ch))   with (i < sizeof(ch))        and   if((ch[i] == ':') with   (i < sizeof(ch) and if((ch[i] == ':') || strlen(ch) == i)

Comment: @user95711 ok I will post my third answer get an idea from there.

Comment: @user95711 don't edit in my answer instead append you question: like you oldquestion **EDIT** appendnewquestion ...as I did my first answer

Comment: @user95711 I said append your question but you have changed you question.

Comment: :P sry... as I got that answer have changed whole code... As I was telling suppose to do from another function.

Answer (score 4):

you forgot to add `'\0'` at the end of `output[]`. Before `printf("%s\n",output);` add following code:

```
output[k-1] = '\0';
```

next,
I am not too much sure, but for second functionality change you if code below :

```
if(i !=sizeof(ch))
{
    output[k] = ':';
}
```

to following (*add `':'` only if it's present in `ch[]`*)

```
if(i !=sizeof(ch) && memchr(ch, ':', sizeof(ch)))
{
     output[k] = ':';
}
else{
    output[k] = ch[i];
}
```

and include a header file `string.h`.

Give it a try!! and let me know if you have other doubt.

But yes its not like you want *"try and catch or error handling like"*

**EDIT**
I am fixing your error as you commented in my answer:
add following code before `printf("%s\n",output);`

```
output[k-1] = 0;
if(memchr(ch, ':', sizeof(ch))==NULL){
        output[k-2] = 0;
}
```

<sub>**cation:** its not good way to fix errors like this, suggesting you to rewrite your code</sub>

Comment: first one is working  but second one not.. its returning some garbage values !!

Comment: @user95711 I have changed my code(answer) for second and I have checked on my system too..its working!.. please review again and don't forget to add `#include <string.h>`

Comment: why we are checking it after while loop ? Is it possible to parse it before while loop and if input is not  MAC address it should not do any process and return it as it is

Comment: @user95711 correted this error `abadeag !!! ` , check the updated answer...Its always good to add `'\0'` every time you add `char` to `output[]` at next position, also declare output like `char output[128]  = {0}`

Comment: I have changed main() function according to your comments. see the question

Comment: @user95711 beck below my new answer

Answer (score 0):

You have changed your question too many time:

You code pass by arguments:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void function(char* ch);
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    if(argc!=2){
        printf("\n wrong number arguments!\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    function(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
void function(char* ch){
    char output[20]={0};

    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;
    bool flag = false;

    while(i < strlen(ch)) 
    {

        flag = false;
        int j = 0;

        while (j < 2)
        {
            if(ch[i] == ':') 
            {
                if(k != 0) 
                {
                    char temp = output[k-1];
                    output[k-1] = '0';
                    output[k] = temp;
                }
                flag = true;
            } 
            else 
            { 
                output[k] = ch[i];
            }
            i++;
            j++;
            k++;
        }

        if(i !=strlen(ch) && memchr(ch, ':', strlen(ch)))
        {
            output[k] = ':';
            output[k+1] = '\0';

        }
        else{
            output[k] = ch[i];
        }
        k++;

        if(!flag) 
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
    output[k] = 0;

    /*for (i=0;i<sizeof(output);i++)
    {
        printf("%c", output[i]);
    }*/

    printf("%s\n",output);
}
```

run for this code:

**case1**:

```
~$ ./a.out  abcderf
abcderf
```

**case-2** :

```
:~$ ./a.out  0:9:1:C:B:98
00:09:01:0C:0B:98
```

Comment: I suppose to store return value in a char name[]=""; like variable... that I suppose to use further !! Its giving me some incomplete pointer type..like wise ..you can checkout the question

Comment: major mistakes in this code `(sscanf(argv[1],"%s",ch)` wrong in your code

Comment: @user95711 Try to understand this code and learn syntax of sscanf, global and local variables ...

Comment: ./a.out  0:9:1:C:B:9     ans. is 00:09:01:0C:0B:9   but it should be 00:09:01:0C:0B:09